# Remove last bit of byte

Tags: java, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I have a byte array, for example (byte array can be more or less than 3 bytes)

```
byte[] array = {0b00000011, 0b00111011, 0b01010101}
```

How can I **remove** the last bit of bytes:
0b**0**0000011, 0b**0**0111011, 0b**0**1010101
because I want to get result like this 11|0111011|1010101
but I have no idea how to do that

Comment: First of all, 0xXXXXXX hexadecimal notation. Instead, use 0bXXXXX.  Secondly, you should use bitwise operators: & (1010&1100 -> 1000), | (1010 | 1100 -> 1110), ^ (1010 ^ 1100 -> 0110) and binary shifts (>> and <<: 10101100>>2 -> 00101011).

Comment: So `myByte & 0b01111111` will preserve only the last 7 bits of `myByte`. The result may be an `int`, if so, just cast it back to a byte: `(byte) (myByte & 0b01111111)`

Comment: You want your result in an `int`, a `String`or as what?

Comment: reading left to right, I would have called this the first bit. You are removing the bit from the representation of the value in text i.e. the String form, a byte always has 8 bits and you can't change that.

Comment: Yeah, I want to save result like integer

Comment: Do you need the leading zero in the second case? If so, then why are there no leading zeroes for 0b00000011?

Comment: Do you want leading zeros or not?

Answer (score 0):

It is not really clear, but perhaps I understand: you want to remove all the non-significant bits in front of a byte. You could use a string for that; in pseudo-code:

```
take a byte value N (or word or whatever)
prepare an empty string ST
while N<>0
  if (N & 1)
    then ST = "1"+ST
    else ST = "0"+ST
  N = N >> 1
end
```

Now the string ST contains what you want (if is that that you want...).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retain leading zeros you can do this.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String sep = "";
for (byte b : bytes) {
    sb.append(sep);
    // set the top byte bit to 0b1000_0000 and remove it from the String
    sb.append(Integer.toBinaryString(0x80 | (b & 0x7F)).substring(1));
    sep = '|';
}
String s = sb.toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    byte[] array = { 0b00000011, 0b00111011, 0b01010101 };
    int result = 0;
    for (byte currentByte : array) {
        result <<= 7; // shift
        result |= currentByte & 0b0111_1111;
    }
    System.out.println(Integer.toBinaryString(result));
```

This prints:

```
1101110111010101
```

If your array is longer than 4 bytes, an undetected int overflow is likely.